# Why Azure AD Graph API might still be appropriate over Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Microsoft strongly recommend to use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph API to access [Azure Active Directory resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog)

There are a very limited number of scenarios for which Azure AD Graph API might still be appropriate according to this [post](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/) written in 2017 May.those Gaps between Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph still exist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
For example Applications and Service principals are only available on the beta endpoint for MS Graph API.
And the beta endpoint is not recommended to be used in production applications.
So if you need to make automation related to app registrations, permissions etc., AAD Graph is still the way to do it safely.

Comment: This is just as funny in February of 2020 as it was in Summer of 2018.